# connectedness and compactness of co-finite topology

Tags: general-topology

If we consider co-finite topology on infinite set say integers $\mathbb{Z}$, I.e $\tau=${$\varnothing$} $\cup${$A \subseteq\mathbb{Z}| |\mathbb{Z} \setminus A|<\aleph_0$}  .
Question is Whether it's both connected and compact?

Comment: Alternative description: the closed sets are exactly $\mathbb{Z}$ and all the finite sets; the open sets their complements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\mathbb{Z}$ is not connected, so $\mathbb{Z} = A \cup B$ where $A \cap B = \emptyset, A, B \neq \emptyset$ and $A, B$ are both open and closed. But then $A$ and $B$ are both finite a contradiction. So $\mathbb{Z}$ is connected.

Let $(U_i)_i$ be an open cover of non-empty open subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ .For any fixed $j \in I$, $U_j = \mathbb{Z} \setminus F_j$, where $F_j$ is finite. Then for every $x \in F_j$, pick some $U_{i(x)}$ from the cover with $x \in U_{i(x)}$ (we have a cover, so this can be done). Then
$\{U_j\} \cup \{ U_i(x), x \in F_j\}$ is a finite subcover of the original cover. ($U_j$ covers almost all points, and we need finitely many more to cover the remainder).